# awk pattern matching - compare awk value with a input

Tags: bash, awk

I need some help writing a script that will compare the value(s) from running awk to user input. 
i.e.: 
`cat employee.txt
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
EMPLOYERS=$(awk -F" " '{ print $2}' employee.txt)
echo "Enter the name of an employer: \c"
read employer
If/for/while employer is part of EMPLOYERS, echo a message.`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it simpler:

```
echo "Enter the name of an employer: \c"
read employer
if [[ $(awk -F" " '{ print $2}' employee.txt | grep $employer) = $employer ]]
then 
    echo Found
fi
```

Comment: FAST!!! I didn't know it was that easy. I was trying to do by using awk '{$1 ~/$employer/}') but it returns nothing. However, replacing $employer with actual employer name returns the name if it exists. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: edit: It doesn't work. It says "found" when wrong name is entered. Sorry. I was too excited

Comment: It works when i test it straight in the terminal but doesn't when I add it to an .sh file. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Both you and karakfa answers work; you're the 1st so I'll give you the credit. Now I have to find a way to make it work the way i want it to. Thanks you both for you help :-)

Comment: It works for me in a shell script. Can you show your script?

Answer (score 2):

or simply

```
...
awk -v emp=$employer '$2==emp{print "found"}' employee.txt
```

`-v` flag is for defining `awk` variables, here to pass shell value to script.

Comment: What is awk -v? I can't seem to find any example on google.